# Why is it important that a transformation applied to a metric is monotonic?

Tags: statistics

What does it mean for a function to be monotonic?

Why is it important that a transformation applied to a metric is monotonic?

Comment: this is more appropriate for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions) but a hint is that monotonicity preserves some nice features of metrics such as sub-additvity